# function call returning first character of array output

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, scripting

Sorry, not entirely sure on how to phrase this.

I have the following PHP script that calls 2 functions. Both output an array that is decoded. I only need 1 portion of each array.

```
{
<?php
require_once('sipTrunkDomain.php');

//setup curl connection
//get list of SIP Trunk domains, uses CURL GET, and only return the domain header
function getTrunkDomain(){
$json = sipTrunkDomain();
//$r = json_encode($json);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
    return $arr;
  }
//returns list of trunk domains
$trunks = getTrunkDomain();
//sets domains as an array to be passed to next function
if(!is_array($domain))
$domain = array();
foreach ($trunks as $trunk){
  $domain[] = $trunk['domain'];

}
//print_r($domain);

//uses domain name from above as a variable for the domain information API call
foreach ($domain as $dom){
  if (empty($dom)){
    echo "No Territory";
  }else{
  print $dom . " - Territory is " . getDomTerr($dom)[0] . "\n";
  }
}
?>
```

1st function getTrunkDomain() pulls a list of client names from one function

2nd function getDomTerr() uses the output of the first function as a CURL input to output a global account for the client.

I've got the script working, but its only returning the first character of the getDomTerr() results.

Function 1

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    return $response;
}
}
```

Function 2

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  
  if ($err) {
    echo "Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
      $temp = json_decode($response,true);
      //print_r($temp);
      return $temp[0]['territory'];
      
  }
  }
```

output when run is:

```
domain1 - Territory is u
domain2 - Territory is a
domain3 - Territory is a
domain4 - Territory is u
```

where "Territory is u" should have a multi-character result instead of just the letter u

Any idea as to why this is. If i call function 2 directly with a manual entry for the "domain" it returns the full length string.

As there is sensitive information, I can't show the full curl CURLOP_URL, but it is the output of an insomnia call with the correct output i'm looking for in each individual call.

I'm a noob at this, so looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was already setting ['territory'] in function 2

with the function already setting the return of territory, I was only referencing the 0 location of the output, and with getDomTerr($dom)[0] it was only returning the first letter.

removed the [0] and it now returns the full territory name